# Add a field to each object inside an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I'm parsing XML data of a third party provider.

They include all the information i need for each Team, except their logo.

I have all the logos imported into my project.

Is there a way to add a logo field to each team?

This is my parse method, works perfectly

```
-(void) parseXML{

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"apikeygoeshere"]];

    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    NSString *xmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSDictionary *xml = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:xmlString];

    NSMutableArray *items = [xml objectForKey:@"TeamLeagueStanding"];

    NSString *nullentry = @""; // custom code for specific reason
    NSString *nullentry2 = @""; // custom code for a specific reason

    [items insertObject:nullentry atIndex:0]; // custom code for a specific reason
    [items insertObject:nullentry2 atIndex:1]; // custom code for a specific reason

    [self setTableData:items];
}
```

This is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method, as you will see my logos are being feed from an array that i have inside my code, but if the team that is in 1st place drops to 2nd, the logos won't change position

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StandingsIdent";
    StandingsViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

     NSDictionary *item = [tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {

    long row = [indexPath row];

    cell.cellTeamName.text = [item objectForKey:@"Team"];;
    cell.cellTeamLogo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_teamLogos[row]];
    cell.cellTeamPosition.text = _teamPosition[row];
    cell.cellPlayed.text = [item objectForKey:@"Played"];
    cell.cellWins.text = [item objectForKey:@"Won"]; 
    cell.cellTies.text = [item objectForKey:@"Draw"]; 
    cell.cellLoses.text = [item objectForKey:@"Lost"]; ;
    cell.cellPoints.text = [item objectForKey:@"Points"]; 
    cell.cellInfo.text = _infoLeague[row];

    }

 else {

    }
    }
```

Is it possible to somehow add these logos to each team? so when team "x" moves the logo does too.

Here is the xml data structure after being parsed:

```
{
Draw = 10;
"Goal_Difference" = "-17";
"Goals_Against" = 39;
"Goals_For" = 22;
Lost = 11;
NumberOfShots = 395;
Played = 25;
PlayedAtHome = 13;
PlayedAway = 12;
Points = 22;
RedCards = 5;
Team = Partick;
"Team_Id" = 561;
Won = 4;
YellowCards = 41;
```

}

Thanks ;)

Comment: Isn't it just a case of updating `tableData` with the image based on the team name.  Then the image will move with the rest of the data?

Answer (score 0):

You receive an `NSDictionary`for each team - this is an immutable object so you can't change it. But, you can create a mutable copy of it (so you will have an `NSMutableDictionary`).

When you do:

```
NSMutableArray *items = [xml objectForKey:@"TeamLeagueStanding"];
```

it's unlikely that you actually get a mutable array back (though you might). Again though, you can create a mutable copy if not.

Then, iterate through the teams, create a mutable copy of the dictionary, add the key/value pair that you need for the logo and then replace the original entry in the array with your updated copy.

Or, an alternate approach:

Store your logos in a different dictionary, where the keys are the team names (or unique ids) and the values are the logo image names. Then, instead of `_teamLogos[row]` you would use `_teamLogos[[item objectForKey:@"Team"]]` to get the image name.

Comment: but this will not have the logo change position when the team does

Comment: You mean if the team moves to a different row? Yes, it would (both solutions) - so long as you update the cell correctly.